# Connecting / Linking CIB files to a regular application template in cappuccino

Tags: templates, cappuccino

I'm new to cappuccino framework and I would like to know if there is any way i can link a regular application template to cib files. Let's say i just generated an application using the application template and i would like to re-use some cib files from other application how can i link them to my code files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the cibs into the app directory.

If you want a mainmenu.cib add the following key/value to your info.plist for your app...

```
<key>Main cib file base name</key>
<string>MainMenu.cib</string>
```

Otherwise you can just load views and windows through a view/window controller...

Comment: I'm still having problem connecting dots, I'm using XcodeCapp to create new cibs but they don't show when i call them from the AppController. Do you have any example i can use?

Comment: Thank for your reply, I have already found my way. But by the way do you know of any ruby/python + cappuccino example?